# Not able to create topic with default schema validation true | Confluent Platform

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to create topic using the below command

```
kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server confluent-platform-cp-kafka:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic push.rdes.portfolios --config confluent.value.schema.validation=true
```

However, I am getting the below error:

```
Error while executing topic command : Unknown topic config name: confluent.value.schema.validation
[2021-02-02 06:47:24,918] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Unknown topic config name: confluent.value.schema.validation
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Running the command without --config confluent.value.schema.validation=true works fine.
The whole setup is running in kubernetes using confluent helm chart.

I have tried the same on local setup and do face the same issue when we start the components (zookeeper, kafka, schema registry, ksql server, kafka connect) individually.

However, the command works when we start the cp setup using the "confluent local start" command.

Confluent-platform Version: 5.5.0 and 5.5.1

Answer (score 4):

That configuration is only available in Confluent Server, not Apache Kafka.

You say you are using Kubernetes, so make sure your pod image is `confluentinc/cp-server`, [not `confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka`](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-kafka/values.yaml#L14)

Comment: I can see in the documentation that cp-server is the commercial component of Confluent platform. Is there any way to create topics with schema validation enabled in the community component? Is that supported?

Comment: Topic / server side validation is not supported outside of Confluent Server, only message / client side validation. If you want to lock down specific clients and topics to prevent bad actors, setup ACL policies and certificates